# Read text from structure in c

Tags: c, data-structures

```
struct Text{
       int length;
       char *txt;
};
void print(struct Text myTxt)
{
     while ( myTxt.txt < myTxt.txt + myTxt.length )
     {
           printf("%c", ++myTxt.txt);
     }
}
int main()
{
    struct Text myText;
    char test[] = "long long test text";

    myText.length = sizeof (test) / sizeof (char);
    myText.txt = test;

    print(myText);

    gets();
    return 0;
}
```

I know that print function is wrong, but how to fix it.

Comment: Is your struct's string supposed to be able to contain any null bytes (`\0`) other than the trailing one? If not, then just use `"%s"`, as mentioned by karlphillip and me.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is `print` modifies the struct passed into it. Specifically, to print each character, you're incrementing `myTxt.txt` and then printing that. Your `while` loop is also incorrect: `myTxt.txt < myTxt.txt + myTxt.length` will always be true if `myTxt.length` is greater than zero.

You can fix it like this:

```
void print(struct Text myTxt)
{
     char *txt = myTxt.txt;
     while ( txt < myTxt.txt + myTxt.length )
     {
           printf("%c", *txt++);
     }
}
```

This sets `txt` to `myTxt.txt`, so you can modify `txt` without modifying `myTxt.txt`.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `for (int i = 0; i < myTxt.length; i++) { printf("%c", myTxt.txt[i]); }`. This way you're not touching any pointers in first place.

Comment: @Regexident: I was trying to keep the code as similar to the original as possible.

Comment: @Kanad: Whoops, it should work now. You were previously using `++txt`. It needed to be `*txt++`.

Comment: @Kanad: icktoofay's code works fine for me. And so does my for loop variation of it. @icktoofay: That's what I assumed. ;) I just prefer to avoid pointer shifts though whenever possible. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `myTxt.length` is greater than zero, `myTxt.txt < myTxt.txt + myTxt.length` is always true.

So your while loop never terminates.

[Edit]

Well, I suppose it terminates once the addition overflows an int.  Still probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

This should be alright:

```
void print(struct Text myTxt) {
    printf("%s", myTxt.txt);
}
```

(This of course requires myTxt.txt to be null-terminated but for c string this is common anyway.)

So unless your string should be able to contain additional null bytes you could change your code to this:

```
struct Text{
       char *txt;
};
void print(struct Text myTxt)
{
    printf("%s", myTxt.txt);
}
int main()
{
    struct Text myText;
    myText.txt = "long long test text";
    print(myText);
    return 0;
}
```

You can get the string's length by calling
`strlen(myTxt.txt);`
which IIRC requires:
`#include string.h`

Comment: What if `myTxt.txt` contains null bytes?

Comment: Well, Kanad asked for printing *"text from structure in c"*. Text (a.k.a strings) in C usually contains exactly one null byte at the very end.

Comment: It's true that they *usually* contain a null byte at the end, but having a struct with a length and a `char *` usually means that it's for the purpose of being able to hold null bytes.

Comment: Absolutely true. Another possibility however could be Kanad is simply new to C and not familiar with null termination in C strings (thus using an additional length field), which I kinda took for granted given this being his very first question at SO. Well, we'll see, I guess ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
void print(struct Text myTxt)
{
     int i = 0;
     while (i < myTxt.length )
     {
           printf("%c", myTxt.txt[i]);
           i++;
     }
}
```

What you did wrong: you printed the addresses of each character, and incrementing it.

what `mytxt.txt` is doing is `mytxt.txt = mytxt.txt + 1;` therefore you are creating an infinite loop when you are checking the argument for the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support NULL bytes:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void print(struct Text *myTxt)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < myTxt->length; i++)
    {
        if (isprint(myTxt->txt[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", myTxt->txt[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            int num = (int)((unsigned char)myTxt->txt[i]);
            printf("\\%x", num);
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print(struct Text *myTxt)
{
    printf("%s", myTxt->txt);
}
```

Comment: I updated `print` to output all non-printable characters as "\xx" where xx is the hex code for the char.